# Container as volume pattern in windows/vagrant env

Tags: windows, vagrant, docker

I'm trying to implement [this](http://www.tech-d.net/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/) pattern for persistent storage in my local windows+vagrant+docker environment.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
    guest: 5000, host: 5000
    config.vm.define "db" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.build_dir = "./worker"
            d.remains_running = false
        end
    end
    config.vm.define "app" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.build_dir = "."
            d.create_args = ["--volumes-from=db"]
        end
    end
end
```

Running

```
vagrant up db --provider=docker
```

does not cause to trouble. Then

```
vagrant up app --provider=docker
```

leads to the following complaint

```
Stderr: 2014/10/07 19:50:07 Error: Cannot start container a999e636639be959ce4a39
9755133f24f0e6565cf526fd8bdd9135b522cbe1fd: Container db not found. Impossible t
o mount its volumes
```

Intuitively it makes sense that the two VM's can't talk to each other, but I can't find a way to run multiple containers in one VM. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a name for your db's container and tell vagrant to boot the container in the defined order.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
    guest: 5000, host: 5000
    config.vm.define "db" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.name = "db
            d.build_dir = "./worker"
            d.remains_running = false
        end
    end
    config.vm.define "app" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.build_dir = "."
            d.create_args = ["--volumes-from=db"]
        end
    end
end
```

then run

```
vagrant up --no-parallel
```